# Using DynamicModule and Locator with an external Module

Tags: dynamic, scoping, locator

I wish to call an external `Module`, called `PCA` inside a `DynamicModule`.

Essentially, this would allow me to move points around a graph using the `LocatorPane` and then this would have an effect on the other graph returned using the `PCA` function. This would be a pretty good visualization for the algorithm. However, I think that the points aren't being dynamically passed to the `PCA` `Module`. Why might this be?

I've tried messing around with making the `PCA[dataset]` dynamic, but I'm not sure this even means anything.

```
DynamicModule[
    {point1 = {2, 2}, point2 = {4, 4}, 
     point3 = {5, 5}, point4 = {7, 7}, point5 = {8, 8}},
  {dataset = {point1, point2, point3, point4, point5};
   p1 = 
     LocatorPane[Dynamic[dataset], Dynamic[ListPlot[dataset]]];
   GraphicsGrid[{{p1}, {PCA[dataset]}}, Frame -> All, ImageSize -> Large], 
   Dynamic[dataset]}]
```

Comment: Is PCA interactive or do you want to use Locator Pane as an interactive setter of the Input for PCA?

Comment: Does replacing `PCA[dataset]` with `Dynamic@PCA[dataset]` solve the problem?

Comment: @Karsten7. That solved the problem. Thank you very much. Can I ask why it solved the problem? Kuba - I want the located pane as an interactive setter for the input for PCA - correct.

Comment: Without `Dynamic` it doesn't update, just as `dataset` wouldn't update if you would not have wrapped `Dynamic` around it.